It is safe to revoke execute permission to public role in SSISDB?
In the ssisdb database the public database role has execute permission granted on every stored procedure. It is safe to revoke it?
The procedure list is this:
catalog.add_data_tap
catalog.add_data_tap_by_guid
catalog.clear_object_parameter_value
catalog.create_environment
catalog.create_environment_reference
catalog.create_environment_variable
catalog.create_execution
catalog.delete_environment
catalog.delete_environment_reference
catalog.delete_environment_variable
catalog.delete_project
catalog.deny_permission
catalog.deploy_packages
catalog.deploy_project
catalog.get_parameter_values
catalog.get_project
catalog.grant_permission
catalog.move_environment
catalog.move_project
catalog.remove_data_tap
catalog.rename_environment
catalog.restore_project
catalog.revoke_permission
catalog.set_environment_property
catalog.set_environment_reference_type
catalog.set_environment_variable_property
catalog.set_environment_variable_protection
catalog.set_environment_variable_value
catalog.set_execution_parameter_value
catalog.set_execution_property_override_value
catalog.set_object_parameter_value
catalog.start_execution
catalog.stop_operation
catalog.validate_package
catalog.validate_project
internal.append_event_message
internal.append_executable_statistics
internal.append_execution_component_phases
internal.append_execution_data_statistics
internal.append_message_context
internal.append_operation_message
internal.append_packages
internal.append_parameter
internal.clean_update_packages
internal.create_extended_operation_info
internal.get_decrypted_parameter_values
internal.get_execution_property_override_values
internal.get_execution_values
internal.get_project_internal
internal.get_project_parameter_values
internal.get_server_account
internal.get_updatedpackages
internal.sync_operation_status
internal.sync_parameter_versions
internal.sync_validation_status
internal.update_operation_status
internal.update_package_deployment_status
internal.update_project_deployment_status
internal.update_project_object
internal.update_validation_status

Microsoft doc says this:
"By design, there are permissions granted on views and stored procedures that are assigned to the SQL Server fixed public role. The permissions don't give users access to execute or edit packages, only permissions to interact with the internal mechanism of the SSISDB which in turn determine actual permissions."

why ? What are you trying to fix ? Documentation stated that this doesn't give them access to do anything so why do you want to remove those permission ?

It is a request from the security team. It is a kind of policy that i have to follow unless I have evidence that it is creating application issues.
